# Set a state as a String from Promise<String> Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set the state of my variable named 'apiResponse'. However, typescript kept complaining to me that at `.then((res) => this.setState({ apiResponse: res,})` I kepy the following error :

> Type '() => Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'String': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 41 more.

**Is there a fix for it ?**

I have looked up similar stackOverflow problem but none of them seems to be addressing this. Maybe they have but I do not know how to interpret it as I am still relatively new to typscript. Thanks for the help

```
interface IProps {}

interface IState {
  apiResponse: String;
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  state: IState;

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apiResponse: "",
    };
  }

   callAPI = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
      .then((res) => res.text)
      .then((res) =>
        this.setState({
          apiResponse: res,
        })
      )
      .catch((err) => err);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callAPI;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with calling functions and provide promises correctly.

Replace `this.callAPI` with `this.callAPI()`

Also replace `res.text` with `res.text()`